# Collecting data into one text file maintaining the original directory name, for loop, bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I have a random folders names structure directories as below:

```
Main_directory 
    |__folder1
    |  |__file.txt
    |
    |__Case4
    |  |__file.txt
    |
    |__setup0
    |  |__file.txt
    |
    |__Case3
    |  |__file.txt
```

Each file.txt has one value e.g. `-300`. I am trying to loop through those folders with the random naming and collect the data in one text file in the Main directory maintaining the original directory name as below:

```
Main_directory 
    |__folder1
    |  |__file.txt  e.g. value of -300
    |
    |__Case4
    |  |__file.txt  e.g. value of 1000
    |
    |__setup0
    |  |__file.txt  e.g. value of -0.0005
    |
    |__Case3
    |  |__file.txt e.g. value of -349.666
    |
   results.txt
```

The `result.txt` should contain as below:

```
folder1 -300
Case4   1000
setup0 -0.0005
Case3  -349.666
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't include "thanks" or similar in your question. It adds unnecessary fluff to the reader. See here for more info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it and here:https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Something like `for f in *; do printf $f >> result.txt; printf " " >> result.txt; cat $f/file.txt >> result.txt; done` should get the job done, though thats def not perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In oneliner form:

```
for f in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n"); do printf $f >> result.txt; printf " " >> result.txt; cat $f/file.txt >> result.txt; done
```

In readable many liner form:

```
for f in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n"); do 
    printf $f >> result.txt; 
    printf " " >> result.txt; 
    cat $f/file.txt >> result.txt;
done
```

How it works:

1. Find all sub-directories, that are exactly sub-directories(not sub sub-directories), and print them without the leading `./`:

`find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%P\n"`

2. Append the filename to `result.txt`, without adding a newline:

`printf $f >> result.txt;`

3. Add a space:

`printf " " >> result.txt;`

4. Add the `file.txt` contents:

`cat $f/file.txt >> result.txt;`

One disadvantage of this approach is that it requires `file.txt` to have a trailing newline. You can fairly easily fix this with a `printf "\n" >> result.txt`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this great code. It does exactly what I wanted and it works in any folder names.