# Copying .png images from different folders keeping the original folder names on the png

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Hope everyone is doing good. I am new to this forum. Anyway, I have the directories that have different sub folders. The naming of sub sub directory i.e. case1 and results folder are remained constant naming on the sub directories.

```
Main_directory 
        |__folder1
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
        |
        |__Case4
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
        |
        |__setup0
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
        |
        |__Case3
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
```

I am trying to copy each speed_vs_time.png images from each directory copy them in the Main_directory in a folder title e.g. images the image title as in the example below;

```
Main_directory 
        |__folder1
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
        |
        |__Case4
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
        |
        |__setup0
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
        |
        |__Case3
        |  |__case1
        |    |___results
        |      |__ speed_vs_time.png
      images
```

Example on what is in the images folder is below;

```
folder1.png
case4.png
setup0.png
Case3.png
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274618/collecting-data-into-one-text-file-maintaining-the-original-directory-name-for/62274994#62274618 what happen to that post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less the same with the answer I gave on your previous post, here [Collecting data into one text file maintaining the original directory name, for loop, bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62274618/collecting-data-into-one-text-file-maintaining-the-original-directory-name-for/62274994#62274618)

Only this time there is no array.

```sh
mkdir -p Main_directory/images

while read -r files; do
  sub_folder=${files#*Main_directory/}
  file_name=${sub_folder%%/*}
  extension=${files##*.}
  cp -v "$files" "Main_directory/images/$file_name.$extension"
done < <(find Main_directory -type f -name '*speed_vs_time.png')
```